# Symfony2 doctrine complex query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entites `User` and `File`.

I have a `User OneToMany File` relation. The field for relation from User is `fileCommercial`, and from File is `commercial`.

In the entity `File` i have a field `state`.

I need, in one query count all files with state=AAA, state=BBB etc... for a specific user (commercial).

For now i have :

```
             $qb->select('a')
            ->from('ProjectCrmBundle:FiLe', 'a')
            ->leftjoin('a.commercial', 'c')
            ->where('c.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('type', 'Commercial');
```

With this query i can get all files for a user `type=commercial`. How can i get all counters like i said above ?

For example, if my User have 4 files with state AAA, and 3 with state BBB, i need to get theses number in my result... Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. It'll return an array that contains a field for state and one for the count. You'll probably have to inspect/var_dump it for the exact layout.

```
$qb->select('a.state, COUNT(c) as count')
->from('ProjectCrmBundle:FiLe', 'a')
            ->leftjoin('a.commercial', 'c')
            ->where('c.type = :type')
            ->groupBy('a.state')
            ->setParameter('type', 'Commercial');
```

Comment: I don't need that, i need multiple count with multiple condition.. count(a.state) as AAA for state=AAA, and count(a.state) as BBB for state=BBB

Comment: That is exactly what `groupBy()` does. In combination with the COUNT(c) it will group the files by state and return the count for each group.

Comment: Yes, the array will have multiple rows. Each linked to a single state; you can pull all the information you need from the results.